# The image is nt getting converted into text.I am using tessOCR

Tags: java, android

I am building an app on OCR where the image is not getting converted in to the text.

TessOCR.java

```
public class TessOCR {
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/AndroidOCR/";
    public static final String lang = "eng";
    private static final String TAG = "TESSERACT";
    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private TessBaseAPI mTess;
    Context context;
    public TessOCR(AssetManager assetManager) {
        Log.i(TAG, DATA_PATH);
        this.assetManager = assetManager;
        String[] paths = new String[]{"sdcard/tesseract/","sdcard/tesseract/" + "tessdata/"};
        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + "eng.traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + "eng.traineddata");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/", lang + ".traineddata"));
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public String getResults(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
        mTess.setDebug(true);
        mTess.init("Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()", "eng");
        mTess.setImage(bitmap);
        String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Main2Activity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra(result,"key");
        return result;
    }

    public void onDestroy() { mTess.end();
    }
}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
mTessOCR = new TessOCR(assetManager);
    processing1();
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.call);
}
private void processing1() {

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new TessOCR(assetManager);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "SCANNing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            new TessOCR(assetManager).getResults(bitmap);
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvv);
            tv.setText(value);
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "SCANNED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            new TessOCR(assetManager).onDestroy();
            //Intent intent = getIntent();
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.veena.cart_for_shopping, PID: 18124
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!
   at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:305)
   at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:282)
   at com.example.veena.cart_for_shopping.TessOCR.getResults(TessOCR.java:70)
   at com.example.veena.cart_for_shopping.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:62)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4796)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19920)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5383)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:734)
```

The app stops when I click on the button and the `getResults()` method is not able to bitmap image according to the logcat.

What's a solution for this?